# reading and writing csv with DictWriter

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

Is it possible to read and write to an existing csv with DictWriter. If not, is there any package available that could do the following:

csv:

```
event_type, flight_number, test_result
'ETA', '1234',''
```

script:

```
testData = csv.DictReader(open('test_data.csv', 'rU'))

for row in testData:

    eventType = row['event_type'].strip()
    flightNumber = row['flight_number'].strip()
    result = 6
    row['test_result'] = result
```

After calculation I want to write to current row of 'test_result' column the value of result.

Comment: Have you considered reading each line in your file and writing the output to a new file?

Comment: Since I'm running test, result has to be in the same file. If there is any package that can do something like this with excel file I'm willing to take that too.

Answer (score 1):

After much tinkering this method seems best until I find a better way.

```
import csv, os

testData = csv.DictReader(open('test_data.csv', 'rU'))
rowHeaders = testData.fieldnames
resultFile = open('result_data.csv', 'w', newline='')
csvWriter = csv.DictWriter(resultFile, rowHeaders)
csvWriter.writeheader()
resultFile.close()

resultFile = open('result_data.csv', 'a', newline='')
csvWriter = csv.DictWriter(resultFile, rowHeaders)

for row in testData:

    eventType = row['event_type'].strip()
    flightNumber = row['flight_number'].strip()
    result = 7

    csvWriter.writerow({'event_type': eventType, 
                        'flight_number': flightNumber, 
                        'test_result': result})
```

Its creating a new file with same exact data + additional data

output result_data.csv :

```
event_type, flight_number, test_result
ETA, 1234,7
ETD, 1034,7
```

Comment: That is correct, but there is no point in closing result_data file to immediately re-open it in append mode: just leave it opened: `csvWriter.writeheader()` can be immediately followed by `for row in testData: ...`

Comment: Worth flagging, even if this example is old, that the U argument in the open method should not have been used since 2016. Instead use the newline= keyword argument. Link to the most recent Python version https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/functions.html#open